# Instantiating an object in the field of other instance

Tags: java

As in the below program, i instantiated an Store object in the Book class member field. Is this command allocates memory inside every Book class object space in heap or once in a free area of heap and assign the address to it ?

```
public class Book{

private String bookName;
private Store count = new Store(10);



public Book(String bookName ) { 
    this.bookName = bookName;
}


public void display(){

    System.out.println(this.bookName);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Book main = new Book("Machines");       
    main.display();
    System.out.println(main.count.bookCount);
}
```

}

Comment: Objects have no memory to allocate.

Comment: Corrected the sentence

Comment: New `Store` object for every book.

Comment: ok But, Is space allocated with in the instance space or outside in heap.

Comment: Objects, including instance fields: heap.

Comment: Check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055375/when-is-memory-allocated-during-instance-creating-or-using-new-keyword-for-objec

Answer (score 0):

Since each instance of the Book class contains their own Store class, this allocates memory for each instance rather than as one heap. If you want to use the same Store instance for every Book instance, you must pass the Store instance into the Book class in the constructor like this

```
public class Book{

private String bookName;
private Store count;



public Book(String bookName, Store count) { 
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.count = count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Store` is a reference type. When you instantiate a reference type, a part of unused heap is allocated to store the actual instance. Then, there will be a "reference" that is stored wherever you currently are. This reference "points" to where the actual object is stored.

Therefore,

The actual `Store` object is stored somewhere else, not inside the `Book` instance. In the book instance, a value is changed to the memory address where the `Store` object is stored at.