# Three Dimensional arrays in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I am not able to create 3D array with pixel value more then (100,100,3) in android. However it is working fine with array les then above mentioned dimension.

My code:

```
double mat[][][] = new double[400][400][3];
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
```

However,

```
double mat[][][] = new double[100][100][3];
```

works fine. I am using emulated virtual machine to run android application.

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably memory. In Android `double` takes 64 bits, which are 8 bytes.

You are creating a 3D array 400x400x3 so the size will be

> 400 * 400 * 3 * 8 = 3.7MB

While the smaller size will be

> 100 * 100 * 3 * 8 = 234KB

It is more likely to get 234KB block of size rather than 3.7MB.

---

Tnx to Luca [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238950/three-dimensional-arrays-in-android/33239172?noredirect=1#comment54281970_33239172).

Comment: you probably meant 64bit. which is 8 bytes. This number depends on the CPU architecture. the ARM architecture that most Android phones have, needs 64bits to represent a double.  400*400*3*8 = 3,66 MB

Comment: Plus a bit more for [array references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839434/pointer-size-how-big-is-an-object-reference).

Comment: Does that means, It is hard to deal with 3D array which takes memory more then above mentioned. What are the ways to deal such issues? Actually i am doing image processing using pictures, mostly i came across point where pixels will be in HD.

Comment: Do you really need to use doubles as each component of a pixel? Usually images are using 8 bits for each component, which can be represented by a byte, so the required memory is 8 times less than what you use now.