# Difference in size of reference variables in Java. (List vs ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I got into an argument with a fellow worker that apart from the advantages [List interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java) has over ArrayList<> for reference variables, we also use List<> interface for an object reference because it is lightweight and would take less memory compared to ArrayList<>.

Is my assumption wrong? Do both List and ArrayList occupy the same amount of space?

I tried searching for reference variables size, [but nothing whetted my appetite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350950/reference-type-size-in-java). I'm not looking for the size of the reference variable in different VMs, but is there a difference in size between different reference variables in the same VM.

Please comment on the question if it is a duplicate, so I can remove. I have searched and read from multiple resources and couldn't come to a conclusion

Comment: What gave you this idea? There's no reason for reference variables of different types to occupy different amount of memory.

Comment: `List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is a class. If you use `ArrayList` to implement the behaviour of `List`, then it's pretty much same.

Comment: Why are you comparing intrerfaces versus classes? List defines the implementation, ArrayList implements a List, as well as LinkedList or another class does. Regarding to the size, a reference to a variable has the same size always.

Comment: @Eran Are you saying both the reference variables take the same amount of memory? I got the general idea because ArrayList's reference would have more functionality than a List's reference and I thought they would differ in size.

Comment: A reference is just that: a reference and it doesn't matter what it refers to. And the object itself won't change either, because it would be an `ArrayList`. If you refer to it as `ArrayList` or `List` only changes the abilities of the variable, but not the object itself.

Comment: There's the _object_ and then there's the _variable_. The variable only holds a reference, so it takes the same amount of space whatever type it is. The object is still an `ArrayList` if you create it with `new ArrayList`, even if you put it in a `List` variable; so it takes the same amount of space. So your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Actually it depends on the JVM implementation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All reference variables are of the same size, yes. This is addressed somewhat tangentially in the JVM specifiation in a couple of places: [§2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.2):

> Like the Java programming language, the Java Virtual Machine operates on two kinds of types: *primitive types* and *reference types*. There are, correspondingly, two kinds of values that can be stored in variables, passed as arguments, returned by methods, and operated upon: *primitive values* and *reference values*.

*(their emphasis)*

and [§2.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1):

> A single local variable can hold a value of type `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `float`, **`reference`**, or `returnAddress`. A pair of local variables can hold a value of type `long` or `double`.

*(my emphasis)*

As you can see, although it calls out things that have size differences (`int` stored in a single JVM variable vs. `long` stored in a pair of JVM variables, for instance), there's only one kind of reference, which fits in a single JVM variable. (A JVM variable is not the same thing as a variable at the Java source code level, though obviously they're closely related.)

---

In a comment you've said:

> I got the general idea because ArrayList's reference would have more functionality than a List's reference...

This is the source of your misunderstanding. The functionality, etc., isn't contained in the *reference*, it's contained in the implementation (class) associated with what the reference *refers to* (the object). For example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

That declares a variable of type `List` *(hand-waving generics)* that refers to an instance of `ArrayList`, which is an object with an associated implementation (the `ArrayList` class). The reference is just something telling the JVM where the object is in memory, nothing more. You can think of it as a number uniquely identifying the object (or even as a memory address if you like, though it's more complicated than that), though you can never directly interact with the number (address). The implementation (class) isn't *duplicated* for each object (object-specific state data is, but not the methods it uses for instance), but even if it were, that duplication wouldn't be in the *reference* to the object, it would be in the object itself. There are no `List` objects, because `List` is an interface. There are only `ArrayList` objects, `LinkedList` objects, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All the reference types take same amount of memory. A reference is nothing but an address to the memory location where the actual object is stored.

> Reference types hold references to objects and provide a means to
>   access those objects stored somewhere in memory. The memory locations
>   are irrelevant to programmers. All reference types are a subclass of
>   type java.lang.Object.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote without leaving a comment :)

Comment: Haha. True. Even I took a great risk in asking this question :). I think my points will wash away once somebody finds a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an interface which means you can't use it by itself. It is therefore subject to the constraints of whatever concrete class is used to implement it (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.). So the question isn't whether `List` is smaller than `ArrayList`, it is whether `ArrayList` is smaller than `LinkedList` (or any other `List` implementation).

Because variables are just references to a place in memory, there is definitely no size advantage to using a `List` as an object reference compared to `ArrayList` except for the inconsequential size of the .java file

Comment: I was actually referring to reference variables of type List and ArrayList. Sorry, if the question is unclear. Do you want me to change something in question?